# Why does Pilot Lite go off when I turn switch to on

Tags: fireplace

This is a fireplace that I have used for several years.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. In order to fully answer your question more information is needed. Are you trying to light the pilot? What switch are you referring to? A make and model as well as pics of the controls would help. Ypu should also [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you will know how to best use this site.

Comment: Do you mean pilot flame? A pilot light is a phrase from a different industry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hold the switch in pilot position longer before turning it to on.  The pilot light heats up a capillary tube which then holds the pilot valve open keeping the light on.  If you are doing that and it's not working then the valve is shot.  Lighting instructions should be on the inside of the box containing the valve.

Comment: Most of the ones I have worked on are actually thermopiles they actually output a small voltage once heated and the valves are millivolt controlled but you are correct some have an airspace the thermopile is in the center of so it takes at least 30 seconds of heat on the probe to create the voltage to open the valve.+